# Is ZMA really effective?

Tags: recovery, supplements, sleep, muscle-recovery

Is there any scientific evidence showing that ZMA (Zinc monomethionine and aspartate and Magnesium Aspartate) is effective as a supplement for training? It is supposed to help in muscle recovery and sleep. I was suggested to try ZMA, but I can't see any real difference. I searched here, and elsewhere on the web, but I am still unsure what to believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of information about [ZMA on Examine.com](http://examine.com/supplements/ZMA/) is pretty minimal.  However if you break down a couple of the individual components you will get a better picture:

- **[Zinc](http://examine.com/supplements/Zinc/)** has minor effects on many things from depression to skin diseases (like rosacia, psoriasis, and acne).  In each of these cases it does move in the more positive direction, but it's not a major affect.
- **[Magnesium](http://examine.com/supplements/Magnesium/)** has notable affects on reducing blood pressure.  If blood pressure is not a problem then it may not really do much for you.
- **[Vitamin B6](http://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminB6-QuickFacts/)** has some effects with skin diseases and depression.  It supposedly also helps you relax, but it is present in decent portions in poultry.

That said, in the anecdotal reports of people who use ZMA you will have mixed results.  This leads me to believe that some people are non-responders, are not suffering from the things that ZMA addresses, or simply get enough of the components from the food they eat.  I happen to fall in to the range of people where ZMA doesn't really help me.  In fact, I happen to find that ZMA makes my sleep a little more restless.

If you want to help your sleep, then a better supplement would be **[Melatonin](http://examine.com/supplements/Melatonin/)** at a dose of 3mg an hour before bed time.  I find this to be immensely helpful with getting a good night's rest.  Sleep is more restorative to your whole body than ZMA would be.

Comment: I'm 32 Years old, height 171 cm (5.61024 ft) weight 52.9 kg.I joined GYM, eating lot, taking whey protein but I sleep only 5-6 Hrs. Is ZMA supplement help for me ?